# Website on IIS different than on Apache

Tags: css, apache, http, iis

I developed a website and published it on a LAN computer running IIS 6.0 all through my testing phase to make sure it looked correct and worked with all browsers. I heavily used CSS for my layout, a small amount of javascript and ASP only for Server Side Includes. The layout was tested in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE8 and Safari. All working as intended.

When I went to upload my completed website onto my domains host, the website came out looking completely different as well as the css drop-down menu not working. The following URL shows the differences (sorry both screen caps are combined because of link limit on SO):

[Pic](http://i53.tinypic.com/34qral5.jpg)

After investigating a little bit, I discovered that hosting site runs Apache as their server. I also ran the ASP command **Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PROTOCOL")** on both hosts and discovered that my IIS testing host returned **SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1** while the Apache host returns **SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.0**

I am somewhat stuck on where to go from here. Is this difference in server protocols causing my css to be interpreted incorrectly on the Apache server? Can I do anything about it considering my domain hosted server is out of my control? Am I completely off track and should look elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is interpreted by the browser, not the web server. The problem probably has to do with the way your hosting provider supports ASP sites (if it supports that at all).

Comment: If Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PROTOCOL") works then it likely supports it

Comment: From my hosting provider's list of included services:  _Server Side Includes (SSI): Supported, but exec cgi tag not supported  ASP: Uses Sun ONE Active Server Pages v3.6.2_  I am not using the exec command for my ssi, simply _#include file="inc.asp"_

Comment: Hosted server didn't like having an include before declaring DOCTYPE. Took the doctype tag out of my header file and put it on each page.

Answer (score 1):

This smells like wrong file references.

Comment: The references to my external files all appear to be working. My javascript functions properly. My SSI's show up where they should be. My CSS is applied to my website, however portions of it do not show up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the live server is not just getting a fatal error and aborting the execution of the page?

Have you checked your error log in your host control panel?

Answer (score 0):

there could be  some \ (backslash) instead of / (slash) in some path definition. IIS interprets backslash or slash in the same way (Apache doesn't).